# Portfolio allocation question: is it not circular reasoning?

Tags: portfolio-optimization

Is portfolio allocation not circular reasoning?

Say we have a portfolio manager, Michael, and a risk manager, Vito. Michael has a portfolio and would like to determine the optimal allocation of his portfolio. So Michael goes to Vito and says "hey Vito, what is the optimal allocation?". Vito then sets up and solves a portfolio allocation problem. However, in order to do so, Vito needs some input from Michael: the mean returns $\mu$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$ of the market!

Obviously Vito does not know any of this. He's just a risk manager, he can do the math but he cannot predict the future. And sure, he can calculate historical returns and covariances, but they are not reflective of the future. The only person in this context who can provide $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ is thus Michael... however, Michael's current portfolio allocation (before any optimization has been done) has, at least to a certain extent, been made with Michael's views on $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ in mind. Therefore, if we use these as input in our portfolio allocation model, we will find that Michael's current allocation may appear (close to) optimal, not because it actually is, but because Michael's input was used to judge Michael's allocation, which obviously leads to a bias.

So I really don't see what the point of portfolio optimization is? It just seems like circular reasoning, or like being your own judge.

????

Comment: Hi: I think you need to explain in detail what you mean by "michael has a portfolio and wants to determine the optimal allocation of his portfolio".  Do you mean that he has the specific composition of his stocks and bonds and wants to determine what percent to put into each ?

Comment: Any algorithm requires inputs to produce an output. Since Michael is in charge of the portfolio it seems he is the right person to provide these inputs (he could of course delegate the work to others, but he ultimately responsible for approving the inputs). I don't see anything circular in that. Michael is not "his own judge" he is a decision maker who seeks the help of an algorithm to improve his decisions.

Answer (score 2):

You are making some kind of circular reasoning and then dismissing portfolio optimization. I believe you are beeing confused by portfolio optimization on its own and how it's used in practice.

In my opinion, there seems to be 3 problems in your argument:

1. Your reasoning is circular because you assume the risk manager will use the the same expected return and covariance matrix than Michael's and that "a portfolio is optimal" is some kind of absolute statement.
   A risk manager will not do that. His job is to challenge assumptions made by the portfolio manager, hence his view on expected returns will be more conservative: at best 0. While his view on risks should be his own. Risk managers run scenario analysis to assess portfolio's risks.
   Given different assumptions, they will have different opinions of what's a optimal portfolio.
2. It's not because you have found a scenario under which portfolio optimization is useless that it really is. There is actually a great wealth of academic litterature of why portfolio optimization is dangerous and how to remedy it, but this has nothing to do with your argument. See for instance [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/4132/markowitz-mean-variance-optimization-as-error-maximization).
3. Portfolio optimization has merits on his own, independently of who is using it. In it's simplest form it says: if you know your expected return and covariance matrix (say diagonal), then the optimal allocation in the maximal sharpe ratio sense gives optimal position weights: expected return divided by variance. It's already a good insight.